# Use $scope.variable from parent controller only when it's filled

Tags: angularjs

In a simplified explanation, I have two nested controllers in my AngularJS application. `ParentController` has the following code:

```
    var getUrls = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var url = //someUrl

        $http.get(url).success(function(data, status) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    getUrls().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.urls = data.urls;
    });
```

ChildController has:

```
    var url = $scope.urls.tasks_list.url;
```

As you can see, `ChildController` tries to access a `$scope` property, `urls`, which is filled only when its parent's promise is resolved. When both controllers are executed (e.g. the user accesses the child state directly), is there a way to tell Angular to only access `$scope.urls` when it's filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: expose the promise in the $scope:

Parent controller:

```
var getUrls = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var url = //someUrl

    $http.get(url).success(function(data, status) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.urlPromise = getUrls();
$scope.urlPromise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.urls = data.urls;
});
```

Child controller:

```
$scope.urlPromise.then(function(data) {
    doSomethingWith(data.urls.tasks_list.url);
});
```

Note that you should use promise chaining to make your code simpler, and make sure the url promise is rejected if the http request fails, instead of staying pending forever:

```
var getUrls = function() {
    var url = //someUrl
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I was trying to avoid having to use `.then()` every time I need to access the URLs... Seems like it can't be helped then?

Comment: You can use the router's resolve configuration, so that the router only instantiates the scope and the controller, and changes the view, once the promise is resolved.

Comment: Cool, will dig deeper on this approach. Thanks again!